# Closing Application Error via VBA works only in some systems

Tags: excel, vba, cmd, error-handling

I use VBA to run a third party program via CMD prompt, and the third party program intentionally throws an application error to tell when its done.

My problem is that the code I use runs correctly on some Windows 10 systems but not other builds of Windows 10. On a side note, some Windows 7 systems throws a Werfault.exe error, and I make a loop that waits for the Werfault.exe message and closes it.

The purpose of this code is to get rid of this message when the program is done.

How do I make this code work for all Windows systems?

Application error:

> "Sim.exe has stopped working - A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Screenshot of the error:

[image: error]

My VBA code (Windows 10):

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
wsh.Run PathCrnt, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

*Note: `PathCrnt` is location of my third party program*.

My VBA code (Windows 7):

```
    Call Shell(PathCrnt, vbNormalFocus)

   'Kill the error message

For i = 1 To 100000

    If TaskKill("WerFault.exe") = 0 Then Exit For

Next i
```

`Taskkill` Function:

```
Function TaskKill(sTaskName)
    TaskKill = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("taskkill /T /im " & sTaskName, 0, True)
End Function
```

Comment: Application.OperatingSystem will return a text string with the OS version, so you could build an if statement to call the appropriate code

Comment: That could work for combining the Windows 10 and Windows 7 codes, but one of my issues is that the Windows 10 VBA code only works for specific builds of Windows 10, and i'm not sure how to change the code to make it work for the other builds because it gives the same error

Comment: Just to make it more clear, the application error doesn't show up on my WIndows 10 computer, but shows up on another computer with Windows 10, but with a different build